# Fill and Print Template C#

Tags: c#, templates, printing

I am developing an application using C# which is simply the user inputs data, it is saved in a db (which is not SQL Server but MySql) and then prints it.

At this stage the user gave me a template which has the logo and some company information on top, in the middle the lines i need to fill and on the bottom some other information regarding this company.

Is it possible to open this document fill the required lines and print it using c#?

Sorry i cannot provide anything but i am stuck here and can't seem to figure out from where to start?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: What format is the template document in? What have you tried so far? Is this web or windows?

Comment: Format can be whatever i want i mean pdf, word, i am going to do that but he has a specific design. I haven't tried anything yet as i said i don't know from where to start. This is for windows using C#. I honestly searched alot about this but couldn't find an example of what i am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have access to any kind of reporting ie.Crystal Reports or SQL Server Reporting Services. You have one of 2 options, either you need to write a report that mimics his template using one of the technologies above, or you would need to use interops to access MSWord or MSExcel and do it that way. You may be able to use some third party PDF software.

If this was my project I would go the report route.

Comment: Say using crystal reporting will i be able to put data from mysql? And is crystal reporting free? Seems that this customer doesn't have alot of budget

Comment: Yes, when adding the datasource to the report you would just specify the provider as being MySQL instead of SQL

Comment: Seems that crystal report is not free or am i seeing another thing?

Comment: What IDE are you developing in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes i am using visual studio 2015

Comment: There is a developer version available for VS2015 here:

http://tektutorialshub.com/download-crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: Thanks very much for this! So i can create the template in here and when the customer presses print i fill in the report with the needed data and print the report is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is basically the workflow you would follow. The download also includes a crystal report viewer that you can use to display the rendered report to the user before they print it.

If my answer helped you please mark is as the answer.

Comment: Sure will do! I will try it hope i get what i need. Thanks & Regards